# how to get summary of content in following code

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

In my block code i have following code in one case:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->condition('n.status', NODE_PUBLISHED);
    $query->condition('n.type', 'news');
    $nids = $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->orderBy('changed', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $content = '<div class="white_rounded_box">
                    <div class="pos clearfix">
                        <h3><span><img src="'.base_path().path_to_theme().'/images/new_ico.png" width="15" alt="news" />Latest News</span></h3>';
    foreach($nodes as $record)
    {
        $content.='<p>'./*need summarry here*/.'</p>'.l('Read more', 'node/'.$record->nid); 
    }                   
    $content .= '</div>
            </div>';
    $block['subject'] = t('Latest news');
    $block['content'] = $content;
```

How do i get summary of content in there?

Comment: I presume this is Drupal 7 right? always best to tag/title questions specifically ;)

Comment: yes it is drupal7

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look in `$record` in your `foreach` statement and find the content you want. (probably `$record->body`) Since you are polling the database manually (vs. using display_modes like teaser / full) you'll probably have to create the summary yourself.

I suggest using the [truncate_utf8()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--unicode.inc/function/truncate_utf8/6) function which "Truncates a UTF-8-encoded string safely to a number of characters.", it supports adding "...", word boundaries etc.

As for this "looking" into your `$record` var, I suggest using the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), which ships with a function `dpm()` which can take basically any variable and output it in a pretty navigationable message on your page.

Comment: because he's doing a node_load_multiple there is no need for him to change his database query.

Comment: touché missed that bit

Comment: truncate_utf8() doesn't handle properly closing HTML tags. I have found a solution and so far it's performing well http://drupal.se/how-create-teasers-are-html-and-word-safe but I'm still looking for a less hackish solution. Cheers.